# My .png file that I put in the folder doesn't appear in my package

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I don't know what happened but when I put any .png file...It doesn't appear in the package...

I put an image in the folder

[image]

and nothing appears in the package

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reloading the file structure in the text editor?

Answer (score 1):

You have to **put the `.png` file into the source folder (`src`) folder**, not into the output folder (`bin`) which is not visible in Eclipse:

```
TemplateForModding/src/assets/ps/textures/blocks
```

Resources like the `.png` files are copied by Eclipse into the output folder when compiling the Java files.

If you copy it to the directory outside of Eclipse, a refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>) on the project folder may be necessary to see it in Eclipse.